# __all__ not working in __init_.py to allow specific module to import my Python code

Tags: python-3.x, python-packaging

I have three python files as follow

```
ProjDir--> helloworld.py 
ProjDir--> pak--> Mymodule.py
ProjDir--> pak--> __init__.py
```

I have used **all** inside **init**.py to allow only one object 'dic' and this is the normal behavior it suppose to do but **all** is not showing its effect in **init**.py file but when I insert **all** inside Mymodule.py it is showing its effect

I have uploaded .zip file of my code here
[MyProject](https://gofile.io/d/JxhQ2M),
can you please tell me why this is happening.

and one more thing I observe that in the helloworld.py file when I am not using
from pak.Mymodule import *
but instead of that using simple
import pak.Mymodule
then using dir() I am no seeing any imported module even after removing **all** completely

Code of **init**.py file is

```
__all__ = ['dic']  # here it is not working
```

code of Mymodule.py file is

```
# __all__ = ['dic'] # here __all__ it is working
def func( par ):
   return (print ("Hello : ", par))

dic = {1:22, "k1":'rr'}
```

code of helloworld.py file is

```
from pak.Mymodule import *
print(dir())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `__init__.py` to this:

```
from .Mymodule import *
__all__ = ['dic']
```

Change `helloworld.py` to this:

```
from pak import *
print(dir())
```

Then you should get output

```
['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 
'dic']
```

Comment: Yes, it ran successfully but in __init_.py file in the editor window i can see tringle exclamation mark before each line as showing :

'from . Mymodule import*' used; unable to detect undefined names (pyflakes E)
'dic' may be undefined, or defined from star imports: .Mymodule (pyflakes)
'func' may be undefined, or defined from star imports: .Mymodule (pyflakes)

Also if I run __init__.py file it shows in console window “ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package”

Comment: Apart from this :
And whenever i run 'helloworld.py' it run successfully and show the expected result but on every run the first line it show :
"Reloaded modules: pak.Mymodule, pak" and then the expected result but I heard that once the module are compiled .pyc then they will not recreate or I am understanding this wrong?

Comment: another thing i want to confirm is :- when we use from pakName import *  then using dir() will return object name from the imported module
but if we use "import pakName.MoudleName" then dir() won't' return object name from the imported module ?
Please Correct me if I am wrong by saying "Yes, your understanding is right" or "No"

Comment: Second thing:- If suppose there are 3 Moudle.py then how can I insert all three modules object name list in ___all___

e.g. : inside __init__.py file

from .Mymod_1 import *
from .Mymod_2 import *
from .Mymod_3 import *
__all__ = ['Mymod_1.func', 'Mymod_2.func', Mymod_3.func]

# if all three have the same name 'func()' defined then do we use prefix, or how we mention object name from all these three modules in all list, and for object not having similar name how there are written in __all__ list, should we write then as normally we write or using module name prefix with objects?

Comment: I cannot answer your comments about your editor reporting warnings and errors.

Comment: Using `from package import *` imports every name listed in `__all__` into the global namespace of the importing module. Using `import package.module` just makes sure that the module is loaded and doesn't import any names. So your understanding is correct.

Comment: Colliding names can be a problem. You can use `from .submodule1 import func as func1` or just have the user write `import package.submodule1` and then `package.submodule1.func`.